# No suitable Visual Studio instances were found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal, ncurses, vcpkg

**i like to download a library for c++ with vcpkg. ihave this error
This is shoul be a error because is red color in terminal:**
`No suitable Visual Studio instances were found`

**here the entire terminal code if you need it:**

`Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.19042.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti sono riservati.

C:\Users\laaou>.\vcpkg install ncurses
".\vcpkg" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
un programma eseguibile o un file batch.

C:\Users\laaou>cd vcpkg

C:\Users\laaou\vcpkg>.\vcpkg install ncurses
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
ncurses[core]:x86-windows -> 6.2#1
No suitable Visual Studio instances were found

C:\Users\laaou\vcpkg>`

**what is mean? how to solve it.**

now thank to @ChrisMM i can solve it, because i downloaded VS community edition!

but now i have this new error in red color:

`Error: Building package ncurses:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED`

**the entirely code if you nedd it:**

`C:\Users\laaou\vcpkg>.\vcpkg install ncurses
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
ncurses[core]:x86-windows -> 6.2#1
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x86-windows...
Could not locate cached archive: C:\Users\laaou\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives\b1\b1b913bc50ef64f802436d916589a69cf7c714cfce6f1d784a583d5c2ab8928f.zip
Starting package 1/1: ncurses:x86-windows
Building package ncurses[core]:x86-windows...
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_fail_port_install.cmake:96 (message):
Target 'Windows' not supported by ncurses!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
ports/ncurses/portfile.cmake:1 (vcpkg_fail_port_install)
scripts/ports.cmake:141 (include)

Error: Building package ncurses:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then
submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
Package: ncurses:x86-windows
Vcpkg version: 2021-08-12-85ab112d5ee102bc6eac8cdbbfdd173a71374e04

Additionally, attach any relevant sections from the log files above.

C:\Users\laaou\vcpkg>`

Comment: Do you have visual studio installed? Note that VS and VS code are not the same thing. If you do, try the developer command prompt.

Comment: @ChrisMM I have vscode, so i need to download vs? i will do it now

Comment: bro is 8Gb IDE, is this normal, vscode is only <1gb. this new ide is >8GB. I Think is normal

Comment: Or maybe you are missing a ENV variable?

Comment: VS code is an IDE. VS is an IDE, and compiler for multiple languages. Yes, it's larger.

Comment: @TheApache and ChrisMM, now i finish downloading VS community edition. i dont have anymore the last errorr: No suitable Visual Studio instances were found  BUT i have this new error: Error: Building package ncurses:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED 

Comment: I'd recommend making a new question with the new error.